# How to invoke a node.js script in TypeScript / JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a `node.js` script under `/bin` folder. The script is a command line tool that generates `png` files. I use it as `$ node vl2png [input_file_name] [output_file_name]`

I have a `gallery.ts` file which will populate an online gallery. I want to use the `pngs` generated by the `vl2png` script in my gallery. What's the best way to call the node script in my `gallery.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

You can either compile `gallery.ts` to get `gallery.js` and then run that with `node`, or you could install [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) and run `ts-node gallery.ts`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Please note my question is not about how to run the `gallery.ts` file, but how to call the `node.js` script in my `gallery.ts` file.

Comment: Use `child_process.execFile()`.